# C# Dictionary: faster access but less memory footprint

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

I want some advise on the best way to store and access with minimum memory footprint and maximum access performance.

Eg.
for each vehicle make i want to store model and name.

i have some thoughts below:

Option 1:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> values = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
list.Add("2001", "Jetta S");
list.Add("2002", "Jetta SE");
list.Add("2002", "Jetta LE");
values.Add("VolksWagen", list);
```

Option 2:

```
Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> values2 = new Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
<pre lang="xml">List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
list2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2001", "Jetta S"));
list2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2002", "Jetta SE"));
list2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2002", "Jetta LE"));
values2.Add("VolksWagen", list2);
```

Option 3:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> values1 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("2001:Jetta S");
list1.Add("2002:Jetta SE");
list1.Add("2002:Jetta LE");
values1.Add("VolksWagen", list1);
```

- Option 1: faster access of make and
  name but most memory footprint
- Option 2: fast access of make and
  name but    more memory footprint
- Option 3: slow    access of make and
  name (would have    to parse it) but
  less memory    footprint

there would be more than 1500 dictionaries like above.

Any suggestions for fastest access but less memory footprint is appreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: "with minimum memory footprint and maximum access performance." - they are usually opposite constraints (time versus space)

Comment: Won't option 1 just throw an exception for duplicate keys?

Comment: How often are these lists updated?

Comment: Personally I like simple and readable code, unless the code is too slow to run that I'm forced to face the performance issue. I think everyone saw `List<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` would feel a little weird.

Comment: will suggest to create a struct for encapsulating year and make - performance will same as that of KeyValuePair but code would be far more readable.

Comment: @DannyChen I also believe that KVP is unnecessary to begin with, and Tuple would be faster.

Answer (score 22):

`SortedList<TKey,TValue>` is a flat list (so no huge increase in memory footprint), that uses binary-search for access - so `O(log(n))` - so not as fast as `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` at `O(1)` - but much better than a `List<T>` (or other linear search) at `O(n)`.

If you want *fastest* access, you need to use extra memory for a hash-table.

As a side-note, `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` also allows efficient access *by int index*, which is hard for `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, and virtually meaningless for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Obviously in your scenario you may need to *combine* `SortedList<,>` with either nesting or a composite key - but IMO that is going to be your best route for getting a balance of memory and accessor-performance. You could use a dedicated composite key, i.e. an **iummutable** `struct` with the composite key members, overriding `GetHashCode()` and `Equals`, implementing `IEquatable<T>`, and for sorting: implementing `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't choose your data structure primarily by memory "footprint" but by access pattern: What are the most frequent lookups you want to do, how often the structure will be updated and so on.

If you want to fill the structure once and then look up the cars by make and construction year, the first approach seems most reasonable (and readable/understandable).

Btw, given the fact that multiple models can be released in one year, you should probably use a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>`. And if it's really years that you want to store, you shouldn't use strings as keys but `Int16` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Dictionary` with `NameValueCollection`:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, NameValueCollection>();
NameValueCollection list = new NameValueCollection();
list.Add("2001", "Jetta S");
list.Add("2002", "Jetta SE");
list.Add("2002", "Jetta LE");
values.Add("VolksWagen", list);
```

Or with collection Initializers:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, NameValueCollection> 
    { 
        { "VolksWagen", new NameValueCollection 
            { 
                { "2001", "Jetta S" }, 
                { "2002", "Jetta SE" }, 
                { "2002", "Jetta LE" } 
            } 
        } 
    };
```

Although I am no expert on memory footprint, IMHO this will provide you the best access pattern in this particular scenario.

Comment: I agree here , this is the solution i would normally go with

Answer (score 1):

When speaking about access in data structures, it's important to understand the difference between **read** access and **write** access. As for the dictionary, you will get `O(1)` access to `value` by `key` time, but `O(log(n))` write time, if i'm not mistaken. Whe using plain lists, it is always `O(1)` to add, but it is `O(n)` to access data. As for memory footprint, it is pretty much the same:  `O(n)` in the worst case.

How many values do you need to store/access?
According to your code samples,

Option 1: is inappropriate:

```
list.Add("2002", "Jetta SE");
list.Add("2002", "Jetta LE");
```

Keys must be unique, so

Option 2: `Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>` 
is  what you need.

Comment: The `O(1)` to add assumes you are adding to the *end*; **insert** can be expensive for array-based lists (much better for linked-lists, obviously)

Comment: Re the footprint - if the OP's aim is to reduce a memory footprint, a flat `O(n)` may be true but unhelpful; with implementations A and B, A could take 5000 times as much space as B, and still both would be `O(n)`

Comment: @Marc, i've edited my post, added "in the worst case". As for write time, insert doesn't have to be expensive if you keep last index, then just use it. Of course, we should discuss reallocation here, but it doesn't matter in a context of the question :)